# Python integer arithmetic: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, binary, decimal, palindrome

I just write this algorithm that searches for prime palindromic (both binary and decimal) number, but I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 25, in <module>
  File "python", line 10, in isPalindromic
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
```

I can't understand where is my fault. Also I'm not sure if this works, but for me (I'm new in programming) sounds logical.

```
import math
def isPalindromic():

    n = 10

    while True:

        for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):

            if n % i != 0:
                n = str(n)
                new_number = n[::-1]

                if n == new_number:

                    n = int(n)
                    binary = str(bin(n)[2:])
                    binary_new = binary[::-1]
                    if binary == binary_new:
                        return n 

        n = int(n)
        n = n + 1 

a = isPalindromic()
```

Comment: Is the indentation now correct? Because it looks like `n = int(n)` is now outside the `for` loop, which would explain why `n` is a string (and causing `n % i` to fail).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes `n` is an `int`, sometime it is a `string`. When it is a string, `%` is the formatting operator.

Using one variable for both is bound to get you in trouble.

Also, your code can be cleaned up a lot.

```
import math

def is_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

def is_prime_dual_palindromic(n):
    return all(n % i for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)) \
        and is_palindrome(str(n))                              \
        and is_palindrome(bin(n)[2:])

a = is_prime_dual_palindromic(10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `n = int(n)` inside for loop for the case when `n != new_number`. As in this case `n = str(n)` and hence is string, so `n % i` is treated as string formatting operation. And since `n` contains no format derectives, you got your error.

Answer (score 2):

Just change this line:

```
if n % i != 0:
```

To this:

```
if int(n) % i != 0:
```

---

The problem is you are using the `%` operator on a string, not an int. Which means instead of getting the modulus operator, you are getting string formatting operator. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961344/what-does-the-percentage-sign-mean-in-python-3-1) for more information on the `%` in Python.