# How to call an application from a Python script

Tags: python, indentation

I would like to change the output file names using a Python script, then do an image processing task. However, I am getting this error:

```
> unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob
import os

files=glob.glob("*.hdr")
for file in files:
    new_file = file.replace("hdr","exr")
    print(new_file)

 os.system("pfsin %s | pfsoutexr --compression NO %s" (file, new_file))
```

Comment: There's an extra space before `os.system`. Also, `"pfsin %s | pfsoutexr --compression NO %s" (file, new_file)` will result in another error. I think you forgot `%`:  `...NO %s" % (file, new_file))`.

Comment: Thanks @vaultah, now the error is `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python cares about indentation - I believe you want this:

```
files=glob.glob("*.hdr")
for file in files:
    new_file = file.replace("hdr","exr")
    print(new_file)

    os.system("pfsin %s | pfsoutexr --compression NO %s" % (file, new_file))
```

Also, note that I believe you were missing a `%` in `--compression NO %s" % (file, new_file)` (which is why you would get the ''str' object is not callable' error). That `%` sign is a string formatting operator - see the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961365/1849664).

Note the extra spaces before the `os.system()` call. If you were to do it another way:

```
files=glob.glob("*.hdr")
for file in files:
    new_file = file.replace("hdr","exr")
    print(new_file)

os.system("pfsin %s | pfsoutexr --compression NO %s" % (file, new_file))
```

I believe it wouldn't run - `new_file` wouldn't be available to the `os.system` call outside of the `for` loop.