# Questions about the while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

There is a quiz on Coursera that I cannot understand

```py
i = 1
while i % 3: 
    print(i, end = ' ')
    if i >= 10:
        break
    i += 1
```

I expect the output is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, but the actual output is 1 2.
I do not understand what is 'while i % 3', can someone explain this?

Comment: If you want is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 use range(1,10).

Answer (score 2):

The % (modulo) operator in python calculates the remainder from the division of the first number by the second.

E.G: `5 % 3 == 2`

When `i` is incremented to `3` in your program, the result of `3 % 3` is `0`.

In Python, `0 == False`, so when `i` increments to `3` it will then no longer satisfy the while loop condition.

You can try this yourself, by doing:

```
while 0:
    print("Hello world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This stackoverflow answer sums it up quite nicely:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/961351/9822083

The `%` symbol in python means the Modulus operator - possibly more easily understood as the 'remainder'. I believe what you meant to say was 'i < 3'

Answer (score 0):

`%` stands for the modulus operator.

> Returns the decimal part (remainder) of the quotient.
>
> https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html

`while i % 3` keeps executing as long as `i % 3` returns a value that is not `0`, which for the first time is `i = 3`

```py
>>> 1 % 3
1
>>> 2 % 3
2
>>> 3 % 3
0
```

Answer (score 0):

any integer number counts as a 'True' for a while loop and when a 'False' is hit the while loop stops. So that 'if' statement is actually useless or redundant in this code.

```
>>>1 % 3
1 - which means true
>>>3 % 3
0 - which means false so the while loop stops and doesn't even run
```

This then ends the loop as you increment i. All this before the if statement can even run 10 times. So response is 1,2.