# Need more understanding on python statement :- return ["even", "odd"][num % 2]

Tags: python, list, math, slice

Can someone please help me understand exactly how the logic is working in below statement of python -

```
return ["even", "odd"][num % 2]
```

This function is correctly returning even /odd values.

Comment: This is explained in some answers here: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`["even", "odd"]` is a list with two elements, thus with the indexes 0 and 1.

It is indexed (`[]`) with `num % 2`.

If `num` is even, `num % 2` is `0`, and `["even", "odd"][0]` is `"even"`.

If `num` is odd, `num % 2` is `1`, and `["even", "odd"][1]` is `"odd"`.

Answer (score 2):

The `%` sign is the [mathematical modulus function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961344/what-does-the-percentage-sign-mean-in-python). `num % 2` will return 0 when num is even, and 1 when num is odd. This value is then used to return the corresponding element of `["even", "odd"]`.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply returning a string. The proper value from list `["even", "odd"]` is extracted using the remainder(`num%2`).

For example, let's say `num` is 4. So, `num%2` is 0 . In this case the 0th element of the list (i.e. `even`) will be returned.

Now if `num` is 5, the remainder will be 1 and the string in position 1 will be returned (in this case `odd`). Notice there is no other possible outcome of `num%2` even for negative numbers, so no chance of accessing an index which is out of range.

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers_list = list(range(10))
def odd_even(any_list):
    odd = []
    even = []
    for element in any_list:
        if element % 2 == 0:
# 10 % 2 = 0, 10 % 3 = 1, 10 / 4 = 2(2) => 10 % 2 = 2
            even.append(element)
        else:
            odd.append(element)
    return odd, even
# there are two way for answers. first - when element % 2 = 0 , so this is even number
# and second - when element % 2 = 1, so this is odd number

print(odd_even(numbers_list))

# if we'll want to run the code output will like this:
# ([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question