# what does it mean by %x after num variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. The following code confuses me and I don't understand properly how it works, especially the code block `if num%x==0`. Can anybody explain it?

```
num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
for x in range(2,num):
    if num%x==0:
        print("{} is not prime".format(num))
        break
else:
     print ("{} is prime".format(num))
```

Comment: Please first read the python documentation before start to ask questions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers

Comment: Duplicate: [What does the percentage sign mean in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961344/what-does-the-percentage-sign-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

`%` is the modulus operator. `num % x` returns the remainder when num is divided by x; thus, if `num % x` is zero then `num` is evenly divisible by `x`, there being no remainder after the division is performed.

Comment: Thanks bob for remind me the use of modulus operator..