# meaning of "%" in printing the result of adfuller in Python

Tags: python, operators

There's a `%` in the following code, which is from [ARIMA Model in Python](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/) .

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from numpy import log

result = adfuller(df.value.dropna())
print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0]) 
print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
```

I'm confused to what the `%` does in the print statement (last line). What does it do to the result?
Or, does it represent mod?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the percentage sign mean in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961344/what-does-the-percentage-sign-mean-in-python)

Comment: See also: *[How do I put a variable’s value inside a string (interpolate it into the string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2960772)*

Comment: @InSync Thank you insync! I was just super confused, since I thought it had something to do with mod -ing the `result[0]`. Now I understand (I think) it alters the string for printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` symbol is related to string interpolation rather then the `print`. It is a way to format string. You can read [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-string-interpolation-with-the-percent-operator/) more about it.

It is just one of [many ways](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) to format strings in python:

> 1. “Old Style” String Formatting (% Operator)
> 2. “New Style” String Formatting (str.format)
> 3. String Interpolation / f-Strings (Python 3.6+)
> 4. Template Strings (Standard Library)

Comment: Thank you! I read the link you've attached; does `%f' % result[1]` in my code actually take a string from result[1] and turns it to a float?  thanks again!